# Query modification without using analytic function

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone please help me out in modifying the below query without using analytic function and aggregate function as i have to use it in creating materialized view with FAST refresh.

```
SELECT bp_id,  
       updtd_dt,  
       RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY bp_id ORDER BY updtd_dt DESC)spec_rn  
FROM tr_ods.ods_bp_specialty  
WHERE updtd_dt IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: SELECT os1.bp_id,  
       os1.speciality_id,  
       os1.updtd_dt,  
                CASE WHEN os1.updtd_dt =(  SELECT MAX (os2.updtd_dt) 
                            FROM tr_ods.ods_bp_specialty os2  
                           WHERE     os2.bp_id = os1.bp_id  
                        GROUP BY os2.bp_id)   
                  THEN  
                        1 
                ELSE 0  
                END AS spec_rn  
           FROM tr_ods.ods_bp_specialty os1

Comment: Is this correct way to implement the above query

Comment: And will it work in mvierw

Answer (score 0):

From [Oracle Database Data Warehousing Guide (12C)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/basicmv.htm#GUID-932B8CD4-BF60-419A-9202-8A9FD5D24024) re aggregates:

> ## General Restrictions on Fast Refresh
>
> ...
>
> It cannot contain analytic functions (for example, RANK) in the SELECT
>   clause.

and

> ## Restrictions on Fast Refresh on Materialized Views with Aggregates
>
> ...
>
> Only SUM, COUNT, AVG, STDDEV, VARIANCE, MIN and MAX are supported for fast refresh.
>
> Aggregate functions must occur only as the outermost part of the
>   expression. That is, aggregates such as AVG(AVG(x)) or AVG(x)+ AVG(x)
>   are not allowed.
>
> For each aggregate such as AVG(expr), the corresponding COUNT(expr)
>   must be present. Oracle recommends that SUM(expr) be specified. See
>   Requirements for Using Materialized Views with Aggregates for further
>   details.

I can't see any way you could simulate the `RANK()` function under these limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery on same table name in Inner/outer Query.